# FFMPEG Output Framecount Different On Audio Files PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

I am using FFPROBE to get some file durations in PowerShell.

For my video it gets the frame count properly but for my audio files it returns a different frame count.

This is my code:

```
$audioId = "$id.m4a"
$videoId = "$id.mp4"
$duration1 = ffprobe -i $videoId -show_frames 2>&1 | grep -c media_type=video
$duration2 = ffprobe -i $audioId -show_frames 2>&1 | grep -c media_type=audio
echo $duration1
echo $duration2
```

For video it returns a proper output, but for audio it returns a wrong result.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Frame counts mean something different for compressed audio? What's the use-case for the result?

Comment: @Gyan its for an edl file, to import to adobe premier

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. As far as I know EDLs don't use frame counts.